# Desenhando linhas no unity3D modo 2D

Tags: unity3d, 2d

Estou desenvolvendo um game 2D e gostaria de desenhar a trajetória do lançamento de um objeto. Porém sou novo no unity3D (o objetivo do game é ganhar experiência na plataforma), eu sei o que preciso para fazer a trajetória o que eu quero é saber como desenhar linhas no unity programando.

Comment: De uma olhada na documentação da unity, neste [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html) fala alguma coisa como desenhar linhas.

Comment: Esta minha resposta tem o desenho de trajetória usando vários objetos de "pontos" que são alinhados conforme o traçado planejado para o projétil: [Calcular força para atingir ponto B a partir de ponto A](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134045/73).