# Calcular força para atingir ponto B a partir de ponto A

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Tenho o valor do ponto inicial, do ponto final (alvo) e o angulo inicial do objeto.

Gostaria de saber qual a força para atingir o ponto final, como na imagem a baixo.

Existe alguma formula matemática ou no próprio Unity que eu possa usar para fazer o calculo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basicamente isso é balística (física de parábolas). Dá uma olhada aqui: http://fisicamoderna.blog.uol.com.br/arch2007-09-02_2007-09-08.html

Comment: Se você conhece a gravidade, pode determinar a **velocidade** inicial necessária, sim, mas pra falar de "força" é preciso também considerar a massa do projétil e o tempo em que a força será aplicada a ele. Acho provável que exista algo impl

Comment: Já implementado no próprio Unity no caso da velocidade, mas no caso da força deve ser necessário estabelecer parâmetros adicionais. Não tenho certeza contudo. P.S. Foi mal, postei o comentário sem querer, e não encontro opção de editar (estou no Android)

Comment: O Unity já tem a física implementada. Mas a exibição da trajetória, por exemplo, precisaria ser criada por você. Esse exemplo de trajetória é interessante porque na prática ele usa o mesmo cálculo de física que eu já havia mencionado anteriormente. Você pode usá-lo pra tentar calcular a força: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/display-projectile-trajectory-path-in-unity

Comment: boa balistica aplicada no exemplo 1

Comment: @bigown Essa resposta vale uns 1000 pontos, mas minha estranheza deriva do fato, que em perguntas simples, se o user não põe um tico de código ele é alvejado por não cumprir certas políticas, no entanto, essa é o tipo de pergunta "faz pra mim"... Num foi sinalizada ou qualquer algo assim...Realmente os parâmetros para perguntas e respostas, não estão claros para um novato como eu...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Física Relacionada

A força que atua no projétil no momento que ele é lançado (e, consequentemente, a velocidade com que ele se move na parábola) é um vetor dado por dois componentes (em termos de um jogo bidimensional, claro): um componente no eixo X (a força ou velocidade na horizontal) e um componente no eixo Y (a força ou velocidade na vertical):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assumindo que não há resistência do vento e que o projétil não tem propulsão (isto é, não é um míssil que acelera ou desacelera por conta própria), a velocidade na horizontal (resultante de uma força inicialmente aplicada) *é constante*. Isto é, ela não muda até o projétil parar por ter se chocado com algo. Assim, o deslocamento horizontal é regido pelo Movimento Uniforme (MU), e dado por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(**equação 1**: ou seja, espaço final = espaço inicial + velocidade x tempo)

Assumindo o mesmo para o projétil em termos da movimentação vertical (sem atrito, propulsão, etc), a velocidade vertical *não permanece constante* porque sobre ela atua *a todo o momento* a aceleração da gravidade ([image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]). Assim, o deslocamento vertical é regido pelo Movimento Uniformemente Variado (MUV), e dado por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(**equação 2**: ou seja, espaço final = espaço inicial + velocidade x tempo + aceleração x tempo ao quadrado)

Na verdade, como o movimento inclui uma aceleração, a velocidade se altera constantemente. E por isso, ela é dada por:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(**equação 3**: velocidade final = velocidade inicial + aceleração x tempo)

Além disso, quando uma força é aplicada em um projétil, a velocidade com que ele vai se movimentar depende da massa do projétil. Quanto mais pesado o projétil for, maior precisa ser a força inicial nele aplicada para que ele se mova com a mesma velocidade. Essa relação é dada pela fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(**equação 4**: ou seja, força = massa x aceleração)

Por isso, a simulação de física pode ser realizada utilizando-se essas fórmulas para calcular, a cada instante do tempo, a posição (tanto no eixo X como no eixo Y) em que o projétil deve estar.

### O que você deseja

O que você deseja fazer, então, é calcular o vetor de força necessário para o primeiro impulso no projétil, dadas as posições inicial (de onde o projétil sai, ou seja, [image: S0]) e final (o alvo do projétil, ou seja, [image: S]). Isso pode ser **estimado** com o seguinte pseudo-código:

```
velocidadeX = forca / massa
tempo = (alvo.x - x) / velocidadeX
velocidadeY = gravidade * (tempo / 2);
```

A primeira linha usa a equação 4 para calcular uma velocidade no eixo X a partir de uma força *qualquer* (que vc pode chutar ou pedir pro jogador informar). Como o movimento horizontal é constante, não importa o valor escolhido! A sacada é justamente calcular a partir dela a velocidade no eixo Y *correta* para que o alvo seja atingido.

Deve ser fácil perceber que quanto menor a velocidade horizontal (isto é, quanto mais devagar o objeto se move "pra frente"), mais tempo ele vai levar pra chegar no alvo. Assim, o projétil precisa também subir mais para que não caia no meio do caminho. Dessa forma, a segunda linha estima o tempo que ele vai levar pra percorrer o eixo horizontal, usando a equação 1.

Finalmente, a velocidade vertical pode ser estimada com a equação 3 de uma forma simples. No movimento de parábola, o projétil vai primeiro subir para então descer, tudo isso no mesmo tempo que o projétil leva para se deslocar horizontalmente. Na subida, ele desacelera, de forma que ao chegar no ponto mais alto a sua velocidade é 0. Logo, na segunda metade do movimento, sua velocidade inicial é 0 (ou seja, [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]) e ele começa a acelerar na queda. Logo, na fórmula, sua velocidade inicial é 0 e o tempo percorrido é a metade do tempo total previamente calculado. A aceleração é a da gravidade (a única atuando sobre o projétil), e está sem o sinal negativo porque na manipulação algébrica da equação 3 ela "passou pro outro lado da igualdade".

Bom, esses são justamente os componentes X e Y do vetor da velocidade inicial que o projétil precisa ter. Você pode calcular o [ângulo do vetor](http://alunosonline.uol.com.br/matematica/angulo-entre-dois-vetores.html) em relação ao eixo X, se desejar, usando o código:

```
angulo = Arco-Tangente(velocidadeY, velocidadeX)
```

Note como eu disse anteriormente (e enfatizei em negrito) que esse código *estima* o vetor de velocidade inicial para o projétil. Por que ele estima? Bom, considere um cenário em que a velocidade X é beeemmm baixa (próxima de 0). Nesse caso, o projétil vai demorar muuiiitoo pra percorrer o espaço horizontal, e assim ele precisa ser atirado quase que pra cima (quase que totalmente na vertical), de forma que vai cair sobre o alvo também quase que totalmente na vertical. Nesse cenário, o cálculo acerta muito bem.

O problema é num cenário em que a velocidade X é beeemm alta. Nesse caso, o projétil vai percorrer o espaço horizontal muito rapidamente, de forma que precisa ser lançado quase que paralelamente ao solo pra acertar o alvo. Esse cálculo simples, então, falha ao desconsiderar o ângulo de inclinação com que o projétil chega no alvo (dessa vez não vai ser mais quase que totalmente na vertical).

Dá pra se pensar em uma solução razoalmente eficaz que "ajusta" o tempo e a velocidade Y reconsiderando o alvo a partir da diferença no espaço horizontal (X) dada pelo ângulo de impacto previamente calculado. Por exemplo, você pode simplesmente executar novamente as seguintes linhas:

```
tempo = (alvo.x - Seno((90 - angulo)) - x) / velocidadeX
velocidadeY = gravidade * (tempo / 2);
```

Na linha 2, se observa-se um trecho `- Seno((90 - angulo))`. Essa parte simplesmente desconta da posição do alvo o deslocamento dado pelo ângulo (o cateto oposto, ou seja, o seno) de diferença de entrada (90 seria se caisse totalmente na vertical, logo desconta o ângulo de entrada pra se ter o ângulo da diferença).

> **Observação 1**: Com essa solução, esse processo precisaria ser
>   *idealmente* repetido mais vezes de forma iterativa, até que o erro fosse totalmente minimizado (que convergisse). Mas no código que eu
>   produzi eu só fiz uma vez porque foi suficiente para ilustração
>   (acerta quase sempre o alvo, quando nele travado). Mas vc ainda vai
>   observar, pelo tracejado, que há alguma pequena variação de onde o
>   alvo real se encontra no eixo X.
>
> **Observação 2**: Eu não sou físico, então admito que não sei se há uma
>   forma melhor de fazer esse cálculo sem precisar ajustar o ângulo
>   iterativamente. Se alguém tiver uma solução melhor, é bem vindo para
>   compartilhar (pode até mesmo alterar no mesmo código sem problemas!).
>   :)

### Exemplo na Unity3D

O código fonte que eu compartilho a seguir foi construído com base em algumas fontes (mencionadas no final dessa postagem). A movimentação do projétil está a cargo da física da Unity3D. Eu só adicionei um `Rigidybody2D` como você faria normalmente. O cálculo do tracejado usa as mesmas fórmulas mencionadas, mas em sua variação com funções trigonométricas (vide as referências também para detalhes). Só há colisores nos projéteis (balas de canhão) e no alvo. A explosão ao "bater" contra o chão utiliza uma mera verificação de altura (por mera comodidade, e para evitar mais facilmente que balas lançadas muito alto possam eventualmente "errar" um colisor e produzir vazamentos e memória).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código pode ser executado [online em WebGL](http://www.luiz.vieira.nom.br/projects/balistica/) (tenha paciência; demora um pouquinho pra carregar) ou baixado em um [arquivo zip daqui](http://www.luiz.vieira.nom.br/projects/balistica/balistica.zip).

### Código

**Classe de controle do canhão:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

// Classe para controle do canhao
public class CannonControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Prefab do ponto de trajetoria (a ser definido via editor)
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject m_dotPrefab;

    // Prefab do projetil (a ser definido via editor)
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject m_bulletPrefab;

    // Objeto do alvo (a ser definido via editor)
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject m_targetObject;

    // Indicativo se a trajetoria deve ser sempre exibida (se true) ou somente
    // quando o botao do mouse estiver pressionado (se false)
    private bool m_alwaysShowTrajectory = false;

    // Propriedade para permitir alteraçao via checkbox na interface grafica
    public bool alwaysShowTrajectory
    {
        get
        {
            return m_alwaysShowTrajectory;
        }

        set
        {
            m_alwaysShowTrajectory = value;
            if(!m_alwaysShowTrajectory)
                hideTrajectoryPoints();
        }
    }

    // Indicativo se a mira deve ser fixada no alvo
    private bool m_fixedInTarget = false;

    // Propriedade para permitir alteraçao via checkbox na interface grafica
    public bool fixedInTarget
    {
        get
        {
            return m_fixedInTarget;
        }

        set
        {
            m_fixedInTarget = value;
        }
    }

    // Indicaçao de que o mouse esta pressionado
    private bool m_mousePressed = false;

    // Transform com a posiçao da boca do canhao
    private Transform m_cannonMouth;

    // Lista com os pontos de trajetoria utilizados
    private List<GameObject> m_trajectoryPoints;

    // Angulo atual do canhao
    private float m_angle;

    // Transform com o limite vertical para os tracos da trajetoria
    // (obtained by its name)
    private Transform m_verticalLimit;

    // Vetor de força com a qual o tiro sera executado.
    private Vector2 m_force;

    // Inicilizaçao do script
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("limit");
        if(!obj)
            throw new UnityException("A instancia do objeto empty chamado 'limit' nao foi encontrada!");
        m_verticalLimit = obj.transform;

        // Procura pelo objeto filho que marca a boca do canhao
        m_cannonMouth = transform.Find("mouth");
        if(!m_cannonMouth)
            throw new UnityException("A instancia do objeto empty chamado 'mouth' nao foi encontrada!");

        // Cria inicialmente 30 pontos de trajetoria (a lista e ajustada dinamicamente
        // conforme a necessidade)
        m_trajectoryPoints = new List<GameObject>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            GameObject dot = (GameObject) Instantiate(m_dotPrefab);
            dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
            m_trajectoryPoints.Add(dot);
        }
    }

    // Atualizaçao quadro-a-quadro
    void Update()
    {
        // A força de lançamento do projetil e igual ao vetor de distancia do
        // canhao ao ponteiro do mouse.
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 dirMouse = mousePos - transform.position;
        m_force = dirMouse;

        // Desenha uma linha amarela no scene viewer do editor para indicar
        // visualmente o vetor de força
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, mousePos, Color.yellow);

        // Se a mira nao esta fixada no alvo, o jogador que controla o tiro
        // (definindo a direçao e a força do tiro com o mouse)
        if(!m_fixedInTarget)
        {
            // Posiciona o canhao apontando para o mouse
            m_angle = (Mathf.Atan2(m_force.y, m_force.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) - 15;
        }
        // Caso contrario, o jogador so define a força no eixo X com base no mouse
        // (o resto e calculado de forma a garantir que acerte o alvo)
        else 
        {
            // Equipara a "altura" do alvo a do canhao
            Vector2 target = m_targetObject.transform.position;
            //target.y = transform.position.y;

            // Calcula os componentes de velocidade x e y
            float mass = m_bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass;
            float gravity = Physics.gravity.magnitude;

            float velX = m_force.magnitude / mass;
            float time = (target.x - transform.position.x) / velX;
            float velY = gravity * (time / 2);

            // Calcula o angulo de lançamento
            m_angle = (Mathf.Atan2(velY, velX) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) - 15;

            // Ajusta conforme o angulo em que o tiro "deve" atingir o alvo
            time = (target.x - Mathf.Sin((90 - m_angle) * Mathf.Deg2Rad) - transform.position.x) / velX;
            velY = gravity * (time / 2);

            // Calcula a velocidade e forma finais
            Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(velX, velY);
            m_force = velocity * mass;
        }

        // Rotaciona o canhao para o angulo calculado
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, m_angle);

        if(m_alwaysShowTrajectory || m_mousePressed)
            showTrajectoryPoints();

        // Captura o pressionamento/liberaçao do botao do mouse
        // (somente se nao estiver sobre o checkbox da UI)
        if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                m_mousePressed = true;

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                m_mousePressed = false;
                hideTrajectoryPoints();
                shootBullet();
            }
        }
    }

    // Simula o tiro do canhao
    void shootBullet()
    {
        // Cria o projetil e o posiciona na boca do canhao
        GameObject bullet = (GameObject) Instantiate(m_bulletPrefab);
        bullet.transform.position = m_cannonMouth.position;

        // Aplica a força a bala
        Rigidbody2D body = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        body.AddForce(m_force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        // Toca o som do tiro
        AudioSource sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        sound.Play();
    }

    // Exibe os pontos de trajetoria para a força atual.
    // O angulo do tiro esta embutido no vetor de força.
    void showTrajectoryPoints()
    {
        float mass = m_bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().mass;
        Vector2 velocity = m_force / mass;
        float angle = Mathf.Rad2Deg * (Mathf.Atan2(velocity.y , velocity.x));

        // Esse valor e uma estimativa de quanto de tempo passa a cada "quadro"
        // Na pratica, ele serve pra ajustar a distancia entre os pontos no traçado
        // Quanto mais proximo de zero (so nao pode ser zero mesmo!), mais parecido
        // com uma linha o traçado se torna
        float step = 0.03f;

        float time = 0;
        Vector2 currentPos = m_cannonMouth.position;
        for(int i = 0; i < m_trajectoryPoints.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject dot = m_trajectoryPoints[i];
            dot.transform.position = currentPos;
            if(currentPos.y >= m_verticalLimit.position.y)
                dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
            else
                dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;

            float dx = velocity.magnitude * time * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            float dy = velocity.magnitude * time * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) - (Physics2D.gravity.magnitude * time * time / 2.0f);
            currentPos = new Vector3(m_cannonMouth.position.x + dx , m_cannonMouth.position.y + dy ,2);
            time += step;

            // Ajuste dinamico dos pontos necessarios para traçar a trajetoria.
            // Basicamente: se faltam pontos para alcançar o limite vertical,
            // adiciona mais 10 deles na lista.
            if(i == m_trajectoryPoints.Count - 1 && currentPos.y > m_verticalLimit.position.y)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    dot = (GameObject) Instantiate(m_dotPrefab);
                    dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
                    m_trajectoryPoints.Add(dot);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Esconde os pontos de trajetoria
    void hideTrajectoryPoints()
    {
        foreach(GameObject dot in m_trajectoryPoints)
            dot.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Classe de controle dos projéteis:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

// Classe para controle do projetil (bala de canhao)
// A fisica do projetil fica a cargo da Unity, pelo uso
// do componente Rigidbody 2D.
public class BulletControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Transform com o limite vertical para os projeteis
    // (obtained by its name)
    private Transform m_verticalLimit;

    // Inicializaçao do script
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("limit");
        if(!obj)
            throw new UnityException("A instancia do objeto empty chamado 'limit' nao foi encontrada!");
        m_verticalLimit = obj.transform;
    }

    // Atualizaçao quadro-a-quadro
    void Update()
    {
        // Checa se o projetil atingiu o "chao" (dado pelo posiçao vertical do
        // objeto vazio chamado 'limit'). Se atingiu, destroi o projetil.
        if(transform.position.y <= m_verticalLimit.position.y)
        {
            explode();
        }
    }

    // Captura a colisao com o alvo (via um trigger)
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Text score = GameObject.Find ("/Canvas/score").GetComponent<Text>();
        score.text = (int.Parse(score.text) + 1).ToString();

        explode();
    }

    // Captura a colisao com outra bala (via um collider)
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        explode();
    }

    // Anima a explosao
    void explode()
    {
        // Toca a animaçao da exploçao (particulas de fogo)
        ParticleSystem explosion = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        explosion.Play();

        // Toca o som da explosao
        AudioSource sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        sound.Play();

        // Esconde a bala
        GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;

        // Destroy o objeto apos o fim da animaçao
        Destroy(gameObject, explosion.duration);

        // Destroy (e para) esse script imediatamente
        // (para que o som e as particulas nao encavalem)
        Destroy(this);
    }

}
```

### Sites de Referência

- Exibição da trajetória: [How to Display Projectile Trajectory Path in Unity 3D? de Swati Patel](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/display-projectile-trajectory-path-in-unity)
- Cálculos relacionados à balística: [Parábolas Desenhadas Pela Gravidade de Dulcidio Braz Júnior](http://fisicamoderna.blog.uol.com.br/arch2007-09-02_2007-09-08.html)
- Cálculo do alcance de um projétil: [Calculate the Range of a Projectile Fired at an Angle da série For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/calculate-the-range-of-a-projectile-fired-at-an-an.html)

### Créditos

- Imagem de fundo: [MLP Background (RD's House Scene) V1.1 de RCupcake](http://rcupcake.deviantart.com/art/MLP-Background-RD-s-House-Scene-V1-1-292372515)
- Imagem do canhão e das balas: [Medieval Cannon de Oleksandr Melnyk](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photo-medieval-cannon-image37858865) (extraídas do *thumbnail* sem marca d'água [disponível no mesmo site](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/medieval-cannon-37858865.jpg), e utilizadas apenas para *fim não-comercial* de ilustração desta resposta)
- Imagem do alvo: [Summer Reading Challenge de ClipartPanda.com](http://www.clipartpanda.com/clipart_images/summer-reading-challenge-60288244)
- Som de tiro: [Grenade Launcher de LeMudCrab](https://www.freesound.org/people/LeMudCrab/sounds/163458/)
- Som de explosão: [Sharp Explosion, Lots of Debris de Superex1110](https://www.freesound.org/people/Superex1110/sounds/77535/)
- Imagem para textura de fogo nas partículas: imagem de chama do pacote padrão da Unity3D.

Comment: Parabéns @Luiz Vieira da gosto de aprender...