# Como implemento vento numa equação de trajetória?

Tags: c#, unity3d, matemática, jogos, física

Tem um jogo de *tanque* **2D**, usando a **UnityEngine** em C#, em que é jogado na lateral da tela, vendo apenas os lados dos tanques, em que tem o tanque verde e o vermelho. O verde precisa atirar e acertar o alvo vermelho. O jogo lhe dá a **força** e **ângulo**, ambos variam de acordo com sua mira, em alguns turnos é definido um tempo aleatório que varia de **0** à **100**, mas nesse aplicativo que estou criando é possível manualmente você pode definir o **vento** e sua direção, **não querendo dizer que é alterado o vento do jogo, mas sim da trajetória que o aplicativo está calculando**.

> **Nota**: O vento já é gerado de uma forma aleatória de 0 para 100. Com esse aplicativo que estou criando, você apenas calcula a trajetória para te ajudar no jogo.

Notem que o ângulo é espelhado, mas já implementei uma função que nos dá o ângulo exato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O jogo é dividido por turnos. Em todo turno o vento muda junto com sua direção. O vento **varia de 0 para 100**, na direção **direita** ou **esquerda**, nunca maior ou menor que isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**A trajetória pontilhada é o que é projetado nesse aplicativo.** O processo está pronto, a trajetória está sendo exibida, o problema é que **ela não é influenciada pelo vento, qualquer mudança no vento ela irá permanecer sendo influenciada apenas por ângulo e a força, não por vento, eis o problema.**

---

### Grande atualização da pergunta

> Coloquei uma parte importante que estava faltando na pergunta: **o calculo horizontal:**

```
// i seria a posição horizontal(?)
for(int i = 1; i <= 1000 - Xpos; i += 1) {
    // tempo do projétil, que é calculado em base do I
    float t = i / (float) ((power + powerSalt[(int) power]) * Mathf.Cos(angle));
    // altura do projétil, calculada com base no tempo
    float Y = (float) (((power + powerSalt[(int) power]) * Mathf.Sin(angle)) * t - (0.5 * g * t * t));
    // adiciona o ponto obtido, abaixo no "i + Xpos" se ocasiona o ponto horizontal, então o "player.y + y" seria a cordenada vertical
    Vector3 point = new Vector3(Map.toWorldX((float) i + Xpos), Map.toWorldY(player.y + Y));

    // enfim, adiciona o ponto (x, y) da linha
    tracer.line.points3.Add(point);
}
```

> **Resuminho básico:** O valor `Y` é calculado em base do tempo de voo para cada X, basicamente entre 1 à 1.000 (como mostrado na declaração do lopping acima) que são os limites horizontais do jogo. O valor `t` representa o tempo de voo de 0 para a posição i (x).

---

### Como a trajetória é afetada com o vento?

Abaixo está a minha trajetória (a linha contínua) e a trajetória do tiro (a linha pontilhada). O vento que estava presente no jogo era **71**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É percebível que além da altura (*`y`*), o formato e a distância da trajetória também foram alterados com o vento.

Brevemente, minha dúvida é:

- **Como implemento vento nessas formulas?**

Comment: O arrasto aerodinâmico é proporcional ao quadrado da velocidade relativa, então seria uma força adicional, adicionada à que você já tem, você tem de pegar o quadrado da diferença entre velocidade atual do objeto e a velocidade do vento. É também preciso considerar os diversos casos (como vento a favor, que pode até acelerar o objeto em vez de freá-lo)

Comment: É alguma implementação sua em C# de algo similar ao [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) em Java? Se sim, seria bacana compartilhar com a comunidade. :)

Comment: A pergunta é super interessante e muito bacana. Mas dá pra melhorar a clareza em algumas coisinhas. 1) Devo considerar as imagens como uma visão superior (estou olhando os tanques de cima) ou lateral? 2) Pela segunda imagem, parece que o tanque atira pra cima (ou seja, visão lateral e com o projétil fazendo uma parábola), mas o ângulo do tiro considera um eixo 3D ou só 2D? 3) Quando vc diz que "o jogo dá a força e o ângulo", isso quer dizer que já é algo calculado e que o jogador não tem controle (parece que o jogador só controla o vento...)?

Comment: Na resposta do colega @zwitterion vc comentou: "As variáveis VoxT e VoyT também não estão declaradas no meu contexto...". Claro que não. O colega só tentou explicar o cálculo pra vc - você é que precisa tentar implementá-lo **no seu código**. Ainda tá um pouco difícil entender exatamente o que vc quer. Não sou físico, mas a fórmula que você utiliza só considera o vetor da gravidade, então não tem mesmo componente de força em outro eixo que não seja o vertical. Tá faltando ai alguma informação importante de como o seu projétil hoje já percorre alguma distância horizontal.

Comment: De fato, só percebi agora que você não está implementando isso nativamente em C#, e sim usando a Unity3D (pelo uso do `Vector3` ali e pela tag que vc adicionou depois). Devia ter deixado mais claro na pergunta desde o começo. Aliás, já que vc usa Unity, por acaso o projétil está usando a física nativa da engine? Se sim, vc deveria indicar isso! Outra coisa, facilitaria muitíssimo que alguém te ajudasse se vc fornecer um [mcve] para facilitar os testes e implementação.

Comment: Qual o intervalo da variável força?

Comment: Manualmente de 0 à 100.

Comment: As respostas atuais podem até não conter detalhes suficientes, mas a sua pergunta também não contém detalhes necessários. Por exemplo, você ainda não respondeu se a trajetória real (aquela efetuada pelo projétil, com vento e tudo) é calculada por você manualmente ou pela física da Unity. A impressão que eu tenho é que você não faz a mínima ideia de como o código que vc tem funciona (porque foi um "cara" que fez). E ai, meu caro, fica realmente difícil de alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: Eu insisto: se o trecho de código que vc postou é realmente suficiente pra explicar o coportamento do seu projeto hoje, tente preparar um [mcve] com ele. Se conseguir, eu **me comprometo** a testar aqui e tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Olhando todos os comentarios e formulas, eu sinto falta de uma força de aceleração.
Se você implementar uma força de aceleração você consegue aplicar a força da gravidade e velocidade do vento nela.

Comment: Olá novamente. Hoje eu respondi [a essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83010/73), e acho que o que tem lá pode te ajudar com a sua dúvida aqui (se vc ainda a tem, claro). Eu não sei os detalhes da sua implementação, mas talvez lhe seja útil comparar os códigos.

Comment: Pra você implementar um vento "simples" no código que eu postei lá na outra resposta, faça o seguinte: crie um `Vector2` com a força do vento que deseja utilizar, some ele na variável `m_force`, logo antes de ela ser utilizada. O vento vai contar como uma força positiva (se na mesma direção da força atual) ou negativa (se contra a força atual), em ambos os eixos. Observe que: **um vento ativo funciona mais ou menos como a gravidade: está *constantemente* influenciando o projétil - a gravidade só influencia no eixo Y, enquanto que o vento influenciaria nos dois eixos**.

Comment: procure no github, uma biblioteca que tenha uma implementação de teoria do caos. converta a biblioteca para c#. e tente de alguma forma modular o comportamento do vento tal como o procura, e ver qual formula ou conjunto de formulas baseado nesse mesmo principio, que melhor da resposta àquilo que procura

Comment: agradeço o feedback. foi a melhor solução que encontrei, e seria exactamente desta forma que resolveria o problema, caso estivesse diante da mesma situação. por isso mesmo sugeri esta solução como possível resposta ao problema. compreendo que não sega o tipo de resposta que talvez estaggam a espera mas a partir do momento em que eu posso ter uma solução que passe por invocar ou uma função ou um obggecto que gaga alguém implementou, poupo, de certa forma, um pouco de trabalho. atenciosamente, sem mais nenhum assunto

Comment: dê uma olhada nesse código https://github.com/krlgrgn/OpenGL-Particles

Comment: @TiagoMoraisMorgado Leia o que o permagreff disse. A pergunta aqui não é apenas obter o resultado, mas saber como calcular. Mas ainda que usar uma solução de terceiros ajudasse, sua resposta original apenas diz "vai e procure uma outra biblioteca que calcule isso pra você", o que efetivamente também não responde. Poderia ser um comentário, no máximo. Você pode editar sua resposta explicando melhor o que quis dizer, colocando o link para o código que encontrou e, preferencialmente, algum código ou alguma indicação do trecho que resolve o problema. Isso funcionaria bem como um complemento.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Entendendo o código

Esse é o seu trecho de código:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 1000 - Xpos; i += 1) {
    // tempo do projétil, que é calculado em base do I
    float t = i / (float) ((power + powerSalt[(int) power]) * Mathf.Cos(angle));
    // altura do projétil, calculada com base no tempo
    float Y = (float) (((power + powerSalt[(int) power]) * Mathf.Sin(angle)) * t - (0.5 * g * t * t));
    // adiciona o ponto obtido, abaixo no "i + Xpos" se ocasiona o ponto horizontal, então o "player.y + y" seria a cordenada vertical
    Vector3 point = new Vector3(Map.toWorldX((float) i + Xpos), Map.toWorldY(player.y + Y));

    // enfim, adiciona o ponto (x, y) da linha
    tracer.line.points3.Add(point);
}
```

A primeira linha faz um laço que varia de 1 a 1000, e você mesmo disse que esse é o limite espacial do seu campo de jogo. Logo, a variável `i` representa uma divisão discreta do espaço horizontal, ou seja, os valores do eixo X (talvez se tievsse chamado a variável `i` de `x` isso ficasse até mais claro).

A segunda linha, já dentro do laço, calcula o tempo. Como o movimento no eixo horizontal (X) é uniforme (isto é, a velocidade do movimento horizontal é constante, ou seja, não há aceleração/desaceleração), esse tempo é calculado com base na seguinte fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A formula (2) é a variação trigonométrica da fórmula (1), e é a que você utiliza no seu código. Após manipulação algébrica, e considerando-se que o espaço inicial é 0 (já que tudo começa na origem), tem-se:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso, o espaço é `i`, e a velocidade é `power + powerSalt[(int) power]`. Naturalmente, como você tem o ângulo (em radianos), o cosseno do ângulo é `Mathf.Cos(angle)`.

Uma vez tendo-se o tempo que o projétil vai percorrer até o espaço `i` (observe como o cálculo é repetido para cada trajeto crescente), a terceira linha calcula a posição do projétil no eixo Y (vertical) no tempo, utilizando a fórmula do movimento uniformemente variado (em que a velocidade do movimento vertical não é constante, já que há desaceleração na subida e aceleração na descida - a aceleração da gravidade):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A fórmula (4) é a variação trigonométrica da fórmula (3), e é a utilizada no código. Novamente, o espaço inicial é 0 (origem) e a sua velocidade é `power + powerSalt[(int) power]` (sim, *inicialmente* a mesma, embora a velocidade real seja ponderada pela aceleração a cada intervalo de tempo). Além disso, a aceleração da gravidade (comumente chamada de `g` ao invés de `a`) é negativa, já que puxa o projétil para baixo (contrária à direção de lançamento). Por isso há um sinal de `-` no lugar de singla de `+` no código. A linha de código faz também `t * t` para calcular o quadrado do tempo, e multiplica a gravidade por `0.5` para fazer a divisão por 2.

> Nota: deveria ser óbvio que multiplicar por 0.5 é equivalente a
>   dividir por 2:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Finalmente, na quarta linha de código, o ponto no espaço bidimensional é construido a partir dos valores de X e Y calculados anteriormente. Lembre-se que X é o valor dado em `i` (o seu código soma um tal de `Xpos` que eu não sei o que é, mas deve ser algum valor de diferença fixa). Essa linha também mapeaia os valores de X e Y de uma métrica local para global conforme um ajuste da posição do objeto `player` (que eu suponho que seja o tanque). Esse mapeamento provavelmente deve-se ao uso dessas coordenadas serem feitas fora do escopo do tanque (talvez a câmera as utilize, e por isso o mapeamento é necessário).

### Adicionando vento

Uma forma bastante simplificada de adicionar vento seria considerá-lo como uma força adicional *que atua apenas na horizontal*, que seria favorável (se tiver soprando na mesma direção do movimento) ou contrária (se tiver soprando contra a direção de movimento). Como você disse que o seu vento só ocorre no eixo X, deve bastar simplesmente adicionar um valor positivo (se favorável) ou negativo (se contrário) à sua velocidade inicial (isto é, use `power + powerSalt[(int) power] + <VELOCIDADE DO VENTO>` onde quer que a velocidade apareça). Mesmo a velocidade do vento sendo somente horizontal, não tem problema utilizar seu valor também no cálculo do Y (o componente do movimento vertical), já que a posição vai ser ponderada pela inclinação do ângulo de lançamento.

Se, por outro lado, o vento puder ter qualquer direção e sentido, eu diria que é mais apropriado você utilizar [álgebra vetorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ru-M11dfoFA) (considerando tanto a velocidade do projétil como a velocidade do vento como vetores e somando-os para ter o vetor resultante para aplicação ponto-a-ponto no cálculo da trajetória). Nesse caso, utilize *as versões não trigonométricas das fórmulas (fórmulas (1) e (3))*, porque o ângulo de inclinação estará "embutido" na direção do vetor.

Por exemplo, suponha que você tenha a sua velocidade do projétil e do vento definidas como vetores, da seguinte forma:

```
Vector2 veloc = new Vector2(10, 20)
Vector2 vento = new Vector2(2, 0);
Vector2 res = veloc + vento;
```

Ao fazer uma soma vetorial você obtem um novo vetor (`res`) que é uma velocidade "combinada". Observe o gráfico abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O vetor da velocidade do projétil (`veloc`) está em roxo, desenhado a partir da origem (0, 0). O vetor do vento (`vento`) está em verde, também desenhado a partir da origem (0, 0). Esse mesmo vetor do vento também foi desenhado a partir de outra origem, a "ponta final" do vetor de velocidade (ou seja, no ponto (10, 20)), em um azul claro, apenas para demonstrar graficamente a ideia de soma vetorial. O resultado dessa soma é um novo vetor (`res`), desenhado em vermelho, e que resulta no ponto (12, 20). Veja como o vetor resultante (em vermelho) "aponta" para a mesma localidade do "caminho" percorrido pelos dois vetores que foram somados (roxo + verde).

Nesse exemplo, o vetor da velocidade do vento (`vento`) tinha valor 0 no componente vertical (o valor de Y), por isso ele é um vento meramente horizontal (como dá pra perceber claramente no gráfico). Porém, ele poderia ter qualquer direção e sentido. Por exemplo, se ao invés de soprar para a direita horizontalmente com força 2, o vento soprasse em sentido noroeste:

```
Vector2 veloc = new Vector2(10, 20)
Vector2 vento = new Vector2(-5, 7);
Vector2 res = veloc + vento;
```

Teria-se o seguinte gráfico resultante:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que a velocidade original do projétil (em roxo) foi afetada pelo vento (em verde) de forma a produzir uma velocidade resultante apropriada (em vermelho), tal qual anteriormente descrito.

Se você utilizar vetores no lugar de valores únicos para as velocidades, pode utilizar as fórmulas citadas anteriormente pra fazer algo assim:

```
Vector2 veloc = new Vector2(10, 20)
Vector2 vento = new Vector2(-5, 7);
Vector2 s = 0 + (veloc + vento) * t - (g * t * t);
```

Note na última linha como a aplicação da fórmula física (3) continua igual, com a diferença de que o valor resultante espacial (`s`) é agora um vetor (que contém ambos os componentes X e Y).

Observe também que a variável `g`, que hoje no seu código é um valor único, poderia também ser um vetor. A gravidade "natural" seria algo como `Vector2 g = new Vector2(0, -9.8)` (lembre-se que você precisaria voltar o sinal de `+` no cálculo da fórmula, já que o sinal negativo está embutido no sentido do vetor), porque atua só no eixo Y e para baixo. Mas você poderia até implementar uma gravidade diferente num jogo espacial, por exemplo, fazendo algo como `Vector2 g = new Vector2(2, 7)` (essa "gravidade" maluca num jogo puxaria tudo pra cima, e levemente pra direita). :)

Finalmente, observe que, apesar de várias pessoas terem comentado, até hoje *você não descreve* na pergunta como o projétil se move no seu jogo. Você diz que usa a Unity, mas não explica se o movimento do projétil é controlado por você (isto é, fazendo os cálculos da mesma forma como descrito até aqui e a translação manualmente), ou se você simplesmente aplica uma força inicial de impulso e a física da Unity cuida do resto. Como "vento" não é um recurso que exista nativamente na física da Unity, precisaríamos saber também se o vento que você diz já funcionar no projétil (tanto que o traçado real não condiz com o que você desenha) é constantemente aplicado ao corpo rígido do projétil *por algum código seu*. No mundo real o vento é uma força constantemente ativa, de forma similiar à gravidade, e por isso é constantemente aplicado ao projétil que se move. Se você quiser reproduzir isso, vai ter que considerar o vento não como uma velocidade, mas como uma aceleração. Nesse caso, faria mais sentido ter algo como:

```
Vector2 veloc = new Vector2(10, 20)
Vector2 vento = new Vector2(2, 0);
Vector2 g = new Vector2(0, -9.8);
Vector2 s = 0 + veloc * t + ((g + vento) * t * t);
```

Isto é, somando os vetores de aceleração do vento e gravidade para ter a aceleração correta sendo aplicada a cada instante de tempo.

> Para informações sobre as fórmulas, [consulte este site](http://fisicamoderna.blog.uol.com.br/arch2007-09-02_2007-09-08.html). Se
>   precisar, compare o que foi aqui explicado com as explicações nesta
>   [minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134045/73).

Comment: @CypherPotato Você tentou essa abordagem? Explique se o resultado foi o esperado.

Comment: Essa é a resposta mais completa e a que mais se adapta à pergunta, portanto, será marcada como correta, facilitou muito o cálculo, agora só falta converter esses vetores para as coordenadas no mapa :P (vou tentar fazer isso, se não conseguir, é outra pergunta :D). Obrigado!

Comment: show, nos mantenha-nos atualizados!

Comment: @CypherPotato vc se aproximou do resultado esperado com a resposta?

Comment: apaguei o projeto sem querer... :P

Answer (score 27):

Olhando seus cálculos podemos ver que você tem duas maneiras de fazer isso, a fácil (mexendo diretamente na velocidade) e a correta que é criar uma **força de resistência**. E também pelo que se vê na sua imagem a alteração na altura não é causada pela alteração do angulo. [Neste site](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/projectile-motion/projectile-motion_pt.html) você pode ver de maneira didática que consegue chegar no mesmo resultado de duas maneiras diferentes, alterando ou velocidade do projétil ou a resistência do ar.

Vamos começar imaginando que o projeto que você está tentando copiar use a alteração na velocidade, então a questão é, como alterar o vento impactando na velocidade com que o seu projétil é lançado?

A resposta a seguir é parcial para chegar um uma resposta completa precisariamos de algumas (não necessariamente todas) das seguintes informações que não encontrei na descrição:

- Unidades de distância percorridas sem o vento
- Diferença da distância com o vento tendo um valor de 71
- O intervalo da força
- O valor da força nos exemplos
- Unidades de altura alcançada sem o vento
- Diferença entre altura com e sem vento

Lembrando que caso a força no gráfico exibido no lançamento não seja o mesmo com e sem vento, apenas as variáveis anteriores talvez não nos permitam chegar no resultado desejado.

Como não temos a definição original para nos basearmos temos duas opçãos para que o vento tenha efeito na velocidade, a primeira é:

```
float force = (float) (pw + powerSalt[power]) + windForce(100);
```

Enquanto a segunda é:

```
float Vi = (float) (force + windForce(100)) * Mathf.Sin(angle);
```

onde a função windForce tem uma definiçao parecida com a seguinte:

```
float windForce(int max){
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int random = rnd.Next(-max, max + 1);
 float force = random * constant;  
 return force;
}
```

**Atenção**: Apesar de podermos aplicar a função em dois lugares, acredito que a segunda opção é incorreta, por não considerar a alteração da força igualmente em todas as variáveis.

A única coisa que falta para que isso funcione é encontrar a constante que multiplica a força, ela precisa ser relativa ao intervalo da força do lançamento (para que o efeito do vento não seja desproporcional). Você pode tentar descobrir isso na tentativa e erro (chutando), mas recomendo é que use a diferença entre altura e/ou distância percorrida pelo projétil em um mesmo lançamento com e depois sem vento para chegar a constante aplicando fórmulas de lançamento oblíquo. O que acredito ser bem simples de ser aplicado por ser conteúdo de ensino médio/pré-vestibular.

Caso essa ninguém no SO possa te ajudar com isso com certeza na [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) alguém pode te dar uma mão para chegar na sua desejada constante.

---

Agora que temos uma resposta parcial dentro dos dados possíveis, podemos ver como seria a meneira correta de implementar considerando o arrasto (originario da mecânica de fluidos), e como o ar também é um fluido isso pode ser usado. A principal diferença entre calcular a força do vento dessa maneira ao comparar com a forma apresentada anteriormente, é que usando o arasto quanto menor a velocidade, menor o efeito do evento aplicado ao projétil, ou seja, a força do vento muda em cada momento (na vida real isso é a mesma coisa que não permite que um paraquedista ganhe velocidade para sempre).

Temos a [equação do arasto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde 
F(D) é a força do arasto
p é a densidade do fluid
v é a velocidade do objeto,
A é a área de contato
C(D) é o coeficiente de arrasto.

Existem algumas discuções mas para uma esfera outra fórmula equivalente pode ser usada. A equação para calcular o arasto de uma esfera é conhecida como [Lei de Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) e é a seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde as variáveis necessárias para que você aplique esta fórmula são:
Velocidade.

- μ é o Coeficiente de arrasto. (objetos de diferentes formatos tem diferentes coeficientes de arrasto)
- R é o raio (quanto maior o objeto, maior a resitência)
- V é a velocidade atual

Note que como falado anteriormente se aumentarmos a área, a velocidade ou o coeficiente de arasto a força de resistência passa a ser maior.
Pelo fato de esses valores serem considerados nesse caso acredito seriamente que essa não seja a abordagem adotada pelo seu jogo original. De qualquer maneira acredito que na resposta você já tenha o mínimo para calcular o arasto momentaneo, desde que você tenha os valores necessários definidos.

Tenha conciência também que esta abordagem irá obriga-lo a calcular o arasto basicamente como um somatório de cada deslocamento a partir do deslocamento anterior, não obrigatóriamente a `cada deslocamento` mas quanto mais próximo o intervalo mais preciso o resultado, veja mais na referência 4, porém o fato de termos que recalcular o valor já o suficiente para aumentar o custo computacional.

Acredito que esse também seja um dos motivos para algumas bibliotecas de jogos que eu encontrei pela internet utilizarem fórmulas que simulam o comportamento do arasto mas de maneira semelhante e não de maneira equivalente ao comportamento real causado pela resistência no ar.

Espero que tenha ajudado a esclarecer a sua dúvida e espero que quando você chegar em uma resposta que aceitável possa compartilhar com a gente.

---

Apesar de eu acreditar que você já conhece algo sobre para que fosse possível chegar até o estado atual do seu jogo, você pode conferir algum material sobre lançamento oblíquo que talvez te ajudem a chegar em uma solução completa nos links que faltam.

- [Me Salva! CIN25 - Lançamento Oblíquo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3jDHU5zY8Y)
- [Lançamento oblíquo](http://www.colegioweb.com.br/lancamento-de-projeteis/lancamento-obliquo.html)

---

Referências

[1 - How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c) - Inglês

[2 - Arasto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrasto)

[3 - Arasto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) - Em inglês (muito mais detalhado)

[4 - Falling Body with Air Resistance](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth252h/Bogley/w02/resist.html) - Inglês

Answer (score 23):

Depende da direção (ou posicão) do ponto que gera o vento. Veja nesse [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/1wu1x8zj/).Eu fiz um círculo com movimento retilíneo uniforme e uma fonte de vento numa região central do percurso. Perceba que durante o tempo do deslocamento o vento vai atuar, no início acelerando o movimento, em seguida retardando o movimento.  Logo vc pode fazer uma função para ter vento de direção aleatória (se quiser mais emoção). Use `var angulo Math.random()*360` se for em JS. Angulo pode variar aleatoriamente entre 0-360 graus em relação à componente horizontal do deslocamento. Se quiser usar direção fixa exmplo 180 graus (contra o movimento) simplesmente faça `var angulo=180`. O resto não é mais programação e sim física. Funciona na mesma lógica que uma força de atrito (se direção contrária ao movimento. Segundo as leis da aerodinâmica vc aplica a desaceleração ou aceleração se quiser ser preciso ou use força do vento com aceleração constante para facililtar. Nesse ponto é só cinemática sinples.

V=VoT(+/-)(Vt^2)/2. Vamos levar em consideração somente a componente horizontal e vc extrapola para o movimento composto.

```
var angulo = Math.random()*360;//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp
var Vx=0;
var Vy=0;
if(angulo = 0){//Movimento acelerado Vx
   Vx=VoxT+((Vxt^2)/2)
}
else if(angulo = 180){//Movimento retardado
   Vy=VoyT-((Vyt^2)/2)
}

//Note que 90 e 270 não interfere em Vx
```

Extrapole para Vx ou Vy, Vx e Vy, para deixar o jogo interessante.

---

Nota de alteração:
Onde eu escrevo `var angulo` - estou me referindo ao ângulo do vento com o componente horizontal da velocidade e não o ângulo de tiro. Então seria melhor chamar a variável anguloV ou mesmo vento.
Então ficaria assim: `var vento = Math.random()*360` para calcular de maneira aleatória a ação do veto sobre a bala.
Tem uma biblioteca de física-javascript muito legal, mas eu sugiro pesquisar outras ou criar a sua mesmo. [Matter.JS](http://brm.io/matter-js/)

### Outros bons exemplos de utilização da matemáticaXfísicaXprogramação(javascript). Autor [Billy Lamberta](https://github.com/lamberta).

### Trigronametria para animações

1. Rodar um objeto em torno de um ponto - usando o mouse. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/01-rotate-to-mouse.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/01-rotate-to-mouse.html).
2. Movimento vertical suave. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/02-bobbing-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/02-bobbing-1.html).
3. Aplitude, velociadade e centro do deslocamento. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/02-bobbing-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/02-bobbing-1.html).
4. Mov em forma de onda. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/04-wave-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/03-bobbing-2.html)
5. Mov de pulsação. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/05-pulse.html), [Código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/05-pulse.html).
6. Mov de ondas usando 2 ângulos. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/06-random.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/06-random.html).
7. Desenhar uma onda. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/07-wave-2.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/07-wave-2.html).
8. Mov uniforme circular. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/08-circle.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/08-circle.html).
9. Mov Elíptico. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/09-oval.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/09-oval.html).
10. Teorema de pitágoas - calcular distância de pontos. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/10-distance.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/10-distance.html).
11. Distância entre ponto e mouse. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch03/11-mouse-distance.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch03/11-mouse-distance.html).

### Velocidade e aceleração

1. MU 1 eixo. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/01-velocity-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/01-velocity-1.html).
2. MU 2 eixos. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/02-velocity-2.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/02-velocity-2.html).
3. Mov angular seguindo o mouse. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/04-follow-mouse-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/04-follow-mouse-1.html).
4. Rotação. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/05-rotational-velocity.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/05-rotational-velocity.html).
5. MUV 1 eixo. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/06-acceleration-1.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/06-acceleration-1.html).
6. Aceleração interativa (essa é muito boa). [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/07-acceleration-2.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/07-acceleration-2.html).
7. MUV 2 eixos - Interativo. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/08-acceleration-3.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/08-acceleration-3.html).
8. Gravidade - Interativo. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/09-gravity.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/09-gravity.html).
9. Aceleração angular guiada por mouse. [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/10-follow-mouse-2.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/10-follow-mouse-2.html).
10. Nave espacial - [Ex](http://lamberta.github.io/html5-animation/examples/ch05/11-ship-sim.html), [código](https://github.com/lamberta/html5-animation/blob/master/examples/ch05/11-ship-sim.html).

Comment: Sua resposta não faz sentindo com minha pergunta. Eu já tenho as fórmulas prontas, nessa mesma fórmula um cara implementou vento mas não sei como. As variáveis `VoxT` e `VoyT` também não estão declaradas no meu contexto, algo exato.

Comment: O `cara` que fez suas formulas implementou vento na ultima linha `float y = (float) ((Vi * t) - 0.5 * g * Math.Pow(t, 2));` com o sinal negativo. Intreferindo em Vy e consequentemente na distância y e dx. A fórmula dele não interfere em Vx. Eu pensei que a sua pergunta era como implementar a ção do vento e não mostrar onde está a ação do vento.

Answer (score 13):

Cara, se seu projeto for de uma faculdade onde os cálculos devem ser calculados como um engenheiro "calcularia" na vida real levando em conta variáveis de física e etc, desconsidera o que eu vou te dizer, porém, se você apenas precisar de lógica pode tentar isso...

Eu indicaria que o vento pode variar de -100 a 100 (tendo 0 como sem vento, 1 com vento muito forte a favor e -1 com vento muito forte contra), multiplicaria esse valor pelo tempo que o projétil ficaria no ar e adicionaria um X como variável de efeito/escala, aumentando ou diminuindo conforme você desejar, somaria o produto na força.

Pelo que eu entendi, seu projétil não voa, você só precisa da linha, neah? Isso talvez funcione.

O X funcionaria como medidor de intensidade da física do vento sobre o projétil, se você quiser que o projétil sofra muito influência, aumente... se você quiser que ele sofra pouca influência, diminua.

Comment: Como calculo então o tempo que o projétil ficaria no ar? A variável `t` que você se refere? Em que modo de tempo? Milissegundos? Segundos? Minutos? Poderia ser explícito?

Comment: Eu não tinha uma conta no stackoverflow e acabei de criar, portanto, não consigo comentar... eu sou o Vitor que respondeu. haha. Então cara, quanto ao tempo eu me referi a variável T, porém, você pode colocar na medida que ficar melhor... Vento = 30 <br>
Tempo = 2 <br>
X = 1 Força = Força + ( (Vento * Tempo) * X ); Ai no X você coloca um valor para o cálculo se encaixar na sua escala de medidas.